# Invoke-expression through vsts returns exited with code '1'

Tags: mysql, powershell, azure-devops

I have a powershell script:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command:("mysql")
```

and when I release it to my azure server through vsts, it returns:

```
exited with code '1'
```

I noticed it runs

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command
```

How do I get vsts to run the script with the global dependencies on my server?

Answer (score 0):

Without arguments the MySql client is an interactive command but Powershell starts the process non-interactively.

Also check out Invoke-Command and Start-Process as these cmdlet may be more appropriate.